# how to update rows based on previous row of dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a time series data given below:

```
date    product price   amount
11/01/2019  A   10  20
11/02/2019  A   10  20
11/03/2019  A   25  15
11/04/2019  C   40  50
11/05/2019  C   50  60
```

I have a high dimensional data, and I have just added the simplified version with two columns {price, amount}. I am trying to transform it relatively based on time index illustrated below:

```
date    product price   amount
    11/01/2019  A   NaN NaN
    11/02/2019  A   0   0
    11/03/2019  A   15  -5
    11/04/2019  C   NaN NaN
    11/05/2019  C   10  10
```

I am trying to get relative changes of each product based on time indexes. If previous date does not exist for a specified product, I am adding "NaN".

Can you please tell me is there any function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `product` and use `.diff()`

```
df[["price", "amount"]] = df.groupby("product")[["price", "amount"]].diff()
```

output :

```
        date product  price  amount
0 2019-11-01       A    NaN     NaN
1 2019-11-02       A    0.0     0.0
2 2019-11-03       A   15.0    -5.0
3 2019-11-04       C    NaN     NaN
4 2019-11-05       C   10.0    10.0
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert columns witthout naming like [["price", "amount"]]? I have a high dimensional data and I am trying to inject the columns except {"date", "product"}.

Comment: Sure, use something like `cols = ["price", "amount"]` and if you want the other cols then `others = [c for c in df.columns if c not in ("price", "amount")]`

Comment: then you can select all the `others` with `df[others]`.